# Install ColdFusion Builder 2 Update 1 Plug-in in Eclipse 4.3

Tags: coldfusionbuilder

I would like to install ColdFusion Builder 2 Update 1 as a Plug-in for Eclipse 4.3.

The install seems to work without errors but when I attempt to register my license code, I get an error dialog box that says:

"The chosen operation is not enabled."

None of the CFB features appear in Eclipse.

In some of the documentation that I've found it references installing to Eclipse 3.6.

Can CFB 2u1 get installed on Eclipse 4.3?  If not, does someone know which version of Eclipse to use for CFB?  Hopefully it is something recent or I'm doing something wrong for the install.

I don't know if it matters, but I'm running:

- Windows 7 Pro 64-bit
- 16GB RAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [ColdFusion Builder System Requirements page](http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion-builder/tech-specs.html) one needs Eclipse 3.7.1. Having tried to install it on versions later than that, failing, and talking to Adobe about it, they confirmed that one needs *that precise version*. More recent ones won't do. This is a bit subpar on the part of Adobe, but so be it.

Comment: Thanks Adam, that worked.  "subpar" is probably the nicest way to describe Adobe lately...