# Is there a way to get ColdFusion Builder 3 to run using Java 8?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, coldfusionbuilder

I am using Mac OS X El Capitan, with Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17). ColdFusion Builder 3 uses java runtime 1.6.

Is there a way to install CF Builder, but using the current JDK on my machine?

Comment: Does it not just read the JVM path from the system's environment variables?

Comment: Are you writing Java code using Builder? Is that why you need this?

Answer (score 1):

I asked a similar question ([Install ColdFusion Builder 2 Update 1 Plug-in in Eclipse 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370640/install-coldfusion-builder-2-update-1-plug-in-in-eclipse-4-3)) for installing CFB 2x as an Eclipse plug-in.  It seems that the requirements are fairly strict when it comes to CFB.

Here are the install specifications for CFB 3x on the Adobe site:

http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion-builder/tech-specs.html

It looks like this version is stuck with Java 1.7 or Eclipse 4.3.2.

Update: I was able to install Eclipse 4.3.2 (Kepler) with 64-bit JDK 1.7u80.  I had to add the following to the eclipse.ini file:

```
-vm
D:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin
```

The location of your JDK/JRE may be different.

Further Update: I was able to set up Eclipse 4.3.2 (Kepler) to use the latest 1.8u66 JDK.  I modified eclipse.ini after I installed this JDK:

```
-vm
D:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin
```

Eclipse Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details > Configuration has:

```
-vm
D:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

So it looks like it is working with the latest 1.8.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help, but I still can't get it working. When I go to the CF Builder then go to the "Show package contents I get this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wbv7fr2vrzjraag/mac.png?dl=0, but when I view the info.plist & the CFBuilder.ini there is different info. I thought that it would be the same. The info.plist - https://www.dropbox.com/s/plk6l1heub7fgvl/info_plist.png?dl=0 and the CFBuilder.ini - https://www.dropbox.com/s/u0867iy0qgej0w7/CFBuilder_ini.png?dl=0 Now id anybody can help me out, I would appreciate it so much. I can't seem to get this working.

Comment: I think that the solution is to edit the CFBuilder.ini file and change the -vm argument to point to where you have installed the latest JDK/JRE.  Make a backup of the CFBuilder.ini file before you change it.  The examples above are for Windows.  The Mac system should be like linux; no drive letter; it starts with the "/" character for the root folder.

Comment: Note also that the -vm arg should be on its OWN line, with the VALUE (path to the JVM) on the line AFTER it. Otherwise it won't take effect, nor will it error, but Builder will not report it having changed. BTW for a standalone CFB, you can confirm things in Help > Product Details > Installation Details > Configuration.

Answer (score 1):

*Too long for comments*

I am running Windows but my version of ColdFusion Builder 3 is running Java 8 already. I did not make any changes for this.

When I click on Help > Product Details > Installation Details > Configuration (tab) this is what it reports. I am only including some of the java* information under system properties here:

```
java.home=C:\Program Files\Adobe\ColdFusionBuilder3\jre
java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
java.runtime.version=1.8.0_25-b18
java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.specification.version=1.8
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/
java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
java.version=1.8.0_25
java.vm.info=mixed mode
java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vm.specification.version=1.8
java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vm.version=25.25-b02
```

I do have update 65 installed on my machine but Builder is using it's own JRE as noted above.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will specifically request Java 1.6 even if you edit the proper plist file (/Applications/ColdFusionBuilder3/CFBuilder.app/Contents/Info.plist). You can get  Java 1.6 here https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US

Answer (score 0):

You just need to find the eclipse.ini file located beside the eclipse program (or Builder as it were). In there it will have the path to the JDK. Change the path to the JDK on your system.